# Include a txt file in an .ac Ltspice simulation

Tags: ac, ltspice, frequency

I have a .txt file containing measurement of an impedance I have performed.

I know that in .TRAN simulation I can easily include a measured voltage or current (saved in a .txt file) in my LTSpice simulation. However, how can I do the same in an **.ac** simulation? I do not want do go down the road of fitting and deducing the equivalent electrical circuit that will reproduce the same frequency behavior of the impedance of the component I have measured, I'd rather just include the file in my simulation and get the bode diagram.

Comment: If you already have the frequency vs. voltage or frequency vs. impedance then why don't you just plot it? Why do you need to simulate it at all?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I need to use this measure impedance in a more complicated circuit.

Comment: I still think it might be easiest to model the impedance as a combination of inductors, capacitors and resistors despite you saying this: *I do not want do go down the road of fitting and deducing the equivalent electrical circuit that will reproduce the same frequency behavior of the impedance of the component I have measured*

Comment: How is your data saved?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen freq Real Imag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the data and use the old [`FREQ`](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/ABM1/ABM1.htm#freq) syntax. For example:

```
freq real imag
  1   0.3  0.7
  2   0.5  0.2
```

These need to be converted in a `(freq mag phase)` triplet:

```
E1 out 0 FREQ {V(in)}
+ (1, {hypot(0.3,0.7)}, {atan2(0.3,0.7)*180/pi}),  ; needs degrees
+ (2, {hypot(0.5,0.2)}, {atan2(0.5,0.2)*180/pi}),
...
```

Where `V(in)` is assumed to be the input (and needs the curly braces). Since `atan2()` will wrap your phase, you may need to do this externally and unwrap it, then simply include the raw numbers as triplets: `(1 0.762 23.2) (2 0.539 68.2) ...`.

Then simply add `.inc <filename>.txt` in your schematic and probe `V(out)` (which can be changed in the `E1 <output_node> 0 ...` line.

Comment: When I include the file '<filename>' that contains the syntax you presented in the second paragraph, what else am I supposed to do include in my schematic? or just the fact of including the file is enough?

Comment: Another question: can this also be done for a frequency dependent mutual inductive coupling coefficient? Because so far I am only studying the frequency behavior of a resistance and inductance (self).

Comment: @Wallflower The file contains an entry in a netlist, SPICE syntax. Including it will add it to the existing netlist and it will act as an integral part, as if the voltage source (in this case) woud be present in the schematic. I'm not sure I understand your 2nd comment. The `FREQ` syntax only applies to the (old) VCVS/VCCS (found in `[Misc]/Epoly/GPoly`). Its purpose is to allow a PWL format in `.AC`. You can't use coupling with that because the data is fixed, while the coupling changes it. E.g. a simple inductor behaves one way, with coupling, another way. Here, the data cannot be altered.